# Combining styled components props with next neighbor selector not working

Tags: css, sass, styled-components

I am switching from active classes to passing props to styled components and ran into a small problem. The prop passing works fine but it's probably something about the css that is causing trouble.

Before the transition to the props way this part perfectly worked:

```
.element.is-active + .element:before {}
```

The styled components props version I assumed would look like this

```
const Component = styled.div<IComponent>`

    ${({ isActive }) =>
      isActive
       ? `
        + &:before {
         content: none;
        }
       `
       : ''}
}
```

alternatively I tried it this way, but neither is working:

```
+ &:before {
    content: ${({ isActive }) => isActive ? 'none' : ''};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found it by trial and error:
the `&` sign here `+ &:before {` was wrong.

I think in this case SC/css grabbed the active element instead of the normal one, probably resulting in a css selector like

```
.element.is-active + .element.is-active:before
```

So I ended up with:

```
+ :before {
    content: ${({ isActive }) => isActive ? 'none' : ''};
}
```